# C ASCII value of extended character set

Tags: c, ascii, extended-ascii

In [this link](http://devnet.asna.com/documentation/Help_Files/AVR41/ctrlref/ANSI_128_256.htm) you can see that the extended ASCII value is 'ÿ' is 255.

When I try to print it in C typecasted to integer

```
printf("%u \n", 'ÿ');   [In]
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar] [Out]
```

Actually I need to read a file containing four such characters and use their extended ASCII values (characters may have any extended ASCII value from 0 to 255)

Any tips or suggestions on how to do so (I was using `fscanf` to perform this operation but open to other ways/any way).

Comment: Looks like your editing environment is using UTF-8 encoding, meaning that when you write `'ÿ'`, there are actually two bytes between the `'`s,

Comment: Make sure your file *actually* contains the single-byte (ISO8859-1) renditions of these characters.  If the file is UTF-8 encoded instead, that's your problem. Use a hex dump program (`hd` or `od` on Linux) to be sure, if you can.

Comment: Yes the file from which I have to read has utf-8 encoding

Comment: The runtime environment and character set and encoding of your editor may differ from that of your application's runtime, so your test proves little.

Comment: Yeah, "extended ASCII" was an ugly hack to get extra characters before Unicode came along. We have better standards now.

Comment: Do you actually encounter any problem? Please describe! `ÿ` is a specific (worthwhile testing) case because its value could be sign-extended from 255 to -1; however, this particular problem should not show up when the program is not erroneous.

Comment: I am getting wrong ASCII value (the file contains ÿ character 4 times) but on typecasting it I am getting ASCII 191 or 195 (surprisingly both alternatively)

Comment: It's not surprising at all, 195 followed by 191 (i.e. `"\xc3\xbf"`) is the UTF-8 encoding for `ÿ`.

Comment: You need to understand the concept of **encoding**. BTW, there is no such thing as *ASCII value is 'ÿ'*, since ASCII is strictly 7 bit only. The C character constant `'ÿ'` has different integral values depending on the encoding.

Comment: If (as you say) the file will be UTF-8 encoded then you need to read the file using something that already understands UTF-8 or you need to read each character and create your own UTF-8 parser.  Will the file have a UTF-8 BOM?

Comment: Sorry I dont have experience as well as knowledge of encoding currently, will read about it and get back.